# How to set AWS ECS' enable_execute_command value in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I set it this way

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "foo" {
  name             = "bar"
  cluster          = "hoge"
  desired_count    = 1
  launch_type      = "FARGATE"
  platform_version = "1.4.0"

  task_definition = "some_arn"

  network_configuration {
    # something
  }

  deployment_controller {
    type = "ECS"
  }

  enable_execute_command = true

  tags = local.tags

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
    ]
  }
}
```

The terraform plan showed

```
Error: Unsupported argument
An argument named "enable_execute_command" is not expected here.
```

Then how to use it?

From the [document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service) I found it's the same layer as `deployment_controller`. Is it the version problem?

The terraform's version is 0.14.x, aws provider's version is 3.29.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS provider vesrion of `3.29` is **too old**. Please **upgrade** to at least 3.34.

Comment: Thank you. It's really a version issue.

Comment: @Miantian No problem. Glad it worked out.